# Synchronized thread method is executing concurrently - why?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one question about thread. I have following Thread class and creating 2 thread objects.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

    String name="";

    public MyThread(String string) {
        name=string;
    }    

    @Override
    public void run() {
        callMe();
    }       

    synchronized private void callMe() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(name+" = "+i);
        }           
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        MyThread a = new MyThread("A");
        MyThread b = new MyThread("B");

        a.start();
        b.start();
    }       
}
```

When I execute this , output I get is -

```
Started
Started
B = 1
B = 2
A = 1
A = 2
B = 3
A = 3
B = 4
A = 4
B = 5
A = 5
```

I know that  A and B are printed randomly as Thread Scheduler picks it up.

But my question is: why loop is NOT executed one after other? I have used `synchronized` keyword.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `synchronized` method is effectively:

```
private void callMe() {
    synchronized(this) {
        System.out.println("Started");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(name+" = "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you've created two different instances, so `this` will be different for each thread... so they're not synchronizing against each other. If you want to see two threads working with the *same* monitor, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
public final class DemoRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " = " + i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new DemoRunnable();
        Thread a = new Thread(runnable, "A");
        Thread b = new Thread(runnable, "B");
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }
}
```

Then you'll get output like this:

```
Started
A = 1
A = 2
A = 3
A = 4
A = 5
Started
B = 1
B = 2
B = 3
B = 4
B = 5
```

(Although it could be the other way round, of course.)

We still have two threads, but they're calling a synchronized method on the same object (a `DemoRunnable` in this case) so one will have to wait for the other to complete.

A few points:

- Implementing `Runnable` is generally preferred over extending `Thread`; it's more flexible
- Synchronizing on a `Thread` object has its own issues, as the `Thread` class does it itself; try to avoid it
- Personally I don't like synchronizing on `this` anyway - I would usually have a private final variable of type `Object` to represent a monitor that *only* my code knows about... that way I can easily see *all* the code that could synchronize on it, which makes it easier to reason about

Comment: So in your first code snippet it doesn't remain Synchronized `method` right ? it becomes Synchronized `statement`. And second code snippet is an example of Synchronized `method` am I right ?

Comment: @NinadPingale: Yes, but that difference is effectively irrelevant - a `synchronized` method is effectively a normal method with a `synchronized(this)` statement containing the body of the method. (For instance methods; for static methods it synchronizes on the `Class` object.)

Answer (score 9):

Synchronized works per Object. To synchronize across instances you need a shared object to synchronize on.

I.e.

```
private final static Object globalLock = new Object();
// Later 
private void callMe() {
  synchronized (globalLock) {
    System.out.println("Started");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       System.out.println(name+" = "+i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: globalLock has to be compulsorily static..otherwise it doen't work right ?

Comment: The reason to use a static object (rather than an instance object) is so that each instance is synchronizing on the same object.  I recommend declaring `globalLock` as explicitly `private` and as `final` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your Code is equal to this Code

```
 private void callMe(){
       synchronized(this){
           System.out.println("Started");
           for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
              System.out.println(name+" = "+i);
           }
       }                           
 }
```

You just synchronise to the current Object.
If you want to synchronise them to each other your need to synchronise to the class,
like this :

```
private void callMe(){
   synchronized(MyThread.class){
     System.out.println("Started");
     for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          System.out.println(name+" = "+i);
     }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because 2 threads are executing through 2 different objects.

All right, you must have by now realized from the other answers. You are creating 2 separate objects, viz. a and b. Now, when you call the start method, a new thread is started to execute through the run method of the respective (separate not same) objects. The synchronization is indeed on the method but there is exactly one thread running through the callMe method of a and exactly one thread running through callMe method of b. So your expectation that the output should be:

A - 1
A - 2
A - 3
...

is not happening.

Hope this helps

Comment: -1 from me - this is an extremely terse answer. Not enough info to explain why the problem is occurring.

Comment: Ok, ok, I shall elaborate :)