# Why isn't synchronization taking place in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
package atask;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Q3Synchronization 
{
    Integer sum=new Integer(0);

     Q3Synchronization(){
         ExecutorService e=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
         for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
             e.execute(new Sum());
         }
         e.shutdown();

         while(!e.isTerminated()){

         }
         System.out.println(sum);
     }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        new Q3Synchronization();
    }

     class Sum implements Runnable{


        @Override
        public void run() {

            m();

        }
       public synchronized void m(){
             sum=sum+1;
         }
     }

}
```

The question is:

- (Synchronize threads) Write a program that launches 1,000 threads. Each thread adds 1 to a variable sum that initially is 0. You need to pass sum by reference to each thread. In order to pass it by reference, define an Integer wrapper object to hold sum. Run the program with and without synchronization to see its effect.

Comment: Actually, only the headline is a question, but not the lower part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255221/synchronized-thread-method-is-executing-concurrently-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

Object method synchronization/locking works on a per-instance basis.

### Explanation

You are creating 1000 instances of the `Sum` class. Every call to `m()` is synchronized but does not cause any other thread to wait. This is because there are no concurrent calls to the same instance, rather there are calls to different instances. I attached your code with a minor change:

```
     Sum s = new Sum();
     for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
         e.execute(s);
     }
```

If you try this change, you will always get a result of `1000` in your counter variable.

Comment: Correct, program is creating new instance os Sum class for every executor thread. So every runnable thread will have its own instance of Sum class and will not block or synchronize each other while calling method m() on it.

Comment: Hi, I have a class that does this same thing, I used your fix of creating just one instance of the class, it works but after frequent tries, I get values different from 1000. It happens very rarely though, mostly after about 10 runs.

Comment: I posted a gist of the code here https://gist.github.com/f3yisayo/09e4a52d59149a1f065fcc8e96b4b89f

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you are creating `new Sum()` instance and passing it to separate thread. The method `m()` is obtaining lock (every thread when entering in syncronized block must acquire lock) on object. Therefore each thread can execute `m()` method concurrently which breaks your multhreading logic since `(sum = sum + 1)` is not atomic operation.

You can fix it either:

1. change sum variable to [Atomic Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and use `addAndGet()` to perform addition . E.g.

`AtomicInteger sum= new AtomicInteger(0);`

and method `m` to use atomic  integer

`public void m(){sum.addAndGet(1);}`

2.Use the same object to acquire lock, so that method `m` will be syncronized properly. You can achieve it by creating one `sum` instance variable in your constructor like this .

```
final Sum sum = new Sum();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    `e.execute(sum);
}
```